# Spark dataframe na.fill boolean column type

Tags: apache-spark

I am able to fill Numberic & String type columns using:

```
masterDF = masterDF.na.fill(-1)
masterDF = masterDF.na.fill("")
masterDF = masterDF.na.fill(-1.0)
```

But I did not find api to fill boolean type column.
I tried this: `masterDF = masterDF.na.fill(false)` which is not supported.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`na.fill` Boolean type is added at version `2.3.0` and previous versions don't support filling Boolean type column. See the API specs [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions).

Answer (score 8):

You can use `Map` inside `fill` where *key is the column name* and *value* is of `Int`, `Long`, `Float`, `Double`, `String`, `Boolean`.

```
masterDF.na.fill(masterDF.columns.map(_ -> false).toMap)
```

The API document says:

> ```
> /**
> * (Scala-specific) Returns a new `DataFrame` that replaces null values.
> *
> * The key of the map is the column name, and the value of the map is the replacement value.
> * The value must be of the following type: `Int`, `Long`, `Float`, `Double`, `String`, `Boolean`.
> * Replacement values are cast to the column data type.
> *
> * For example, the following replaces null values in column "A" with string "unknown", and
> * null values in column "B" with numeric value 1.0.
> * {{{
> *   df.na.fill(Map(
> *     "A" -> "unknown",
> *     "B" -> 1.0
> *   ))
> * }}}
> *
> * @since 1.3.1
> */
> def fill(valueMap: Map[String, Any]): DataFrame = fillMap(valueMap.toSeq)
> ```

You can even set different values for different columns using `Map` inside the `fill` function.

I hope the answer is helpful.