# How to cartesian some column and sum other column in dataset spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset

I have a dataset using java:

```
+---------+-------------------+------+
|country  |      isNew        |   req|
+---------+-------------------+------+
|       vn|               true|    10|
|       vn|              false|     3|
|       mm|               true|     4|
|       mm|              fasle|     1|
+---------+-------------------+------+
```

I want cartesian column country and isNew with all and sum req. Result look like:

```
+---------+-------------------+------+
|country  |      isNew        |   req|
+---------+-------------------+------+
|      all|                all|    18|
|      all|               true|    14|
|      all|              false|     4|
|       vn|                all|    13|
|       mm|                all|     5|
|       vn|               true|    10|
|       vn|              false|     3|
|       mm|               true|     4|
|       mm|              fasle|     1|
+---------+-------------------+------+
```

Please help me solve this. Thank all for helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.cube("country", "isNew")
  .agg(sum("req") as "req")
  .na.fill("all")
```

Comment: Thank you a lot of, and note some people na.fill with boolean type added at 2.3.0 https://stackoverflow.com/a/51073545/3667812